# How to dynamically set the height in a CSS-class depending on the browser's window size with Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create 2 independently scrollable columns (left and right) using the Bootstrap 3 grid, which should dynamically change their height depending on the browser's windows size and are offset by a top-padding of 100px for a navigation bar. At the moment I have to set a fixed height (600px), which obviously doesn't scale very well on different screen sizes.

**CSS:**

```
.left {
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.right {
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-9 left scrollable">

       // Content Left Column

   </div>

   <div class="col-md-3 right scrollable">

       // Content Right Column

   </div>

</div>
```

I already tried to put them in a #testdiv and change its' height with a Javscript / jQuery solution, which doesn't seem to work:

```
$('#testdiv').height($(window).height() - 100)
```

Would appreciate your advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking to accomplish:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/KPLR8/)

This uses css calc to set the height of the two left/right columns to 100% of the window minus the height of your navigation bar (I used html5 `<aside>` but no reason you can't use div tags with classes if you prefer).

Don't forget, the height of an element is dependent upon the parent element having its height set.  So, in this case, I set the html and body height 100% of the window height using 100vh.  That will constrain the height of the entire page to the height of the window.  If you wanted your main content to not have the independent scroll behavior (from overflow: auto), then set the html/body height to 100% instead.

Here's the core essence of the demo css/html:

**CSS:**

```
body, html {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
nav {
    background-color: palegreen;
    height: 100px;
}
main, aside {
    overflow: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    float: left;
}
main {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: pink;
}
aside {
    width: 25%;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    Navigation
</nav>
<aside>
     Left Aside
</aside>
<main>
    Main Content
</main>
<aside>
    Right Aside
</aside>
```

Comment: `height: calc(100% - 100px);` for both columns with `height: 100vh;` for the body returns `height: calc(0);`. The height is not set at all (using latest Chrome).

Comment: Does the demo work for you? I am assuming that you mean that you're not getting the correct results when you apply these styles to your particular layout.  If I'm wrong let me know, but without seeing your markup it's hard to figure out what the real issue is.  Again, I'd remind you that the parent element(s) need to have a height set.  If you're using Bootstrap, that means, your container and row also need height set.  Here's another demo, slightly different, using a Bootstrap example: http://www.bootply.com/Z1ZSFOMPLb

Answer (score 0):

Use  this in your CSS file :

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1600px) and (max-device-width: 1700px) {

 ////your css codes

 }
```

OR

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 1700px) {

 ////your css codes

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to scale down, use EMs instead of pixels, then change the font-size for smaller screens.

```
@media all and (min-width: 901px){ html{ font-size:100.00%;} }
@media all and (max-width: 875px) and (min-width: 851px){ html{ font-size: 98%;} }
@media all and (max-width: 850px) and (min-width: 826px){ html{ font-size: 96%;} }
etc....

.left {
    height: 37.5em;
    overflow: auto;
}

.right {
    height: 37.5em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: The height should not only scale down but dynamically adapt with any possible screen height. A CSS-only solution will not be able to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

If you really, really want to pin the height of an element to the browser window, you can probably just use fixed positioning.

```
.left, .right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.left {
   left: 0;
   width: 200px;
}

.right {
   left: 200px;
   right: 0;
}
```

[Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates what that does.](http://jsfiddle.net/pGR2P/) Of course, this doesn't look good at all on mobile devices.

Comment: I already tried it with`position: fixed;` with bascially destroys the whole responsive layout and is therefore not an option.